# About Casting in C++'s Class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, constructor, type-conversion

I've been writing c for several years, just get into c++ for some needs!
My book is C++ Primer 5/e, and I've reach the topic about constructor conversion and got some problems

In C++ we have many kinds of casting.
like static_cast, dynamic_cast, and we also have function-like casting which is a kind of explicit casting.

```cpp
class Sales_data{
public:
    //C++11 feature,ask compiler to create a default constructor for us
    Sales_data() = default;
    Sales_data(const std::string &s, unsigned n, double p):
        bookNo(s), units_sold(n), revenue(p*n);
    explicit Sales_data(const std::string &s): bookNo(s){}
    explicit Sales_data(std::istream&);

    Sales_data combine(const Sales_data &item);
private:
    std::string bookNo;      // implicitly initialized to the empty string
    unsigned units_sold;
    double revenue;
};
```

std::string s is an ISBN.
and the forth one read a ISBN from stdin

I know without explicit, the following statements is legal.

```cpp
item.combine(string("ISBN NUMBER"));
item.combine(cin);

//error: need two conversion const char *->temporary string-> temporary Sales_item
item.combine("ISBN NUMBER");
```

I just don't get what are the benefits of making the last two of the constructors explicit?

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

I can't get the point why some of vector's constructors are declared explicit?? What is the reason?

Comment: Em because it's really strange that when one says `do_something(5)` they means passing a vector with 5 elements?

Comment: Neither of your "legal" statements are legal because you can't bind a temporary to a non-const `Sales_data` reference in `combine()`.

Comment: @chris They both look legal to me ... the first passes a temporary to a const-ref, and the second pass a non-temporary (cin) by reference.

Comment: @maditya, `combine()` takes a non-const reference, which is being filled with those temporaries constructed in the function calls.

Comment: @chris Wow, my bad ... I was looking at the constructors, not noticing that you were referring to `combine`.

Comment: @TimHsu if you're asking what the `explicit` keyword does, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121162/what-does-the-explicit-keyword-in-c-mean

Comment: @maditya, I actually had that comment up before, but I did that same thing as well and couldn't believe how crazy I was becoming. It's pi A.M. right now.

Comment: chris is right, it's my mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`explicit` forbids to call the constructor to do the automatic conversion. The constructor can still be used as a normal constructor. Yes, the language should have been designed to have `explicit` constructors by default and annotate (`implicit`?) the conversion constructors... but that's how the story goes.

The reason that `std::vector<T>::vector(int)` is marked as explicit, for example is to forbid the following code:

```
void do_fancy_stuff(const std::vector<std::string> &data);

do_fancy_stuff(20);
```

If the vector constructor is not explicit it will be used to convert the `int` to a `vector` of 20 empty strings, and that makes little sense.

The general idea when writing a constructor `TypeA::TypeA(TypeB x)` is to wonder: "is this constructor *converting* the `TypeB` into a `TypeA` or is it just using `x` as a single parameter? If it is the latter, add `explicit`.

Comment: Thanks @rodrigo, is it possible to discover the problem like this everytime we design our class?

Comment: @TimHsu: Well, look for any constructor that can be called with exactly one parameter and think: "is this a conversion operator"? If "yes" do nothing; if "no" add `explicit`. If in doubt, just add it.